# (Win) Read real-time TCP/IP packets

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

does exists softwares (for windows) that read and automatically order packets (TCP/IP) and discard "wrong" packets?

The problem is that I need to read it in "real time" (for a thirdy party game).

Actually I use tcpdump (C) and try to "order" it with my software (Python) but has many problems.

Obliviously I don't know the real structure of TCP/IP protocol and this is the problem. Therefore does exists software that to do this for me?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by “Wrong packet” ? Do you want to filter packets ?

Comment: @Cukic0d I don't know what is the "correct" meaning, but for example sometimes I receive 2 times the same packet because one of them is corrupted
and this is a problem for my "raw packets parser".

"Do you want to filter packets" Probabily this is what I want to do BUT in real-time.